# How to get data from instagram profile page by Jsoup in android

Tags: android, jsoup, instagram

In an instagram profile page is a button "LOAD MORE" which load more posts.
Image Description
[image]

I want to get "href" attr of this button by jsoup in android. when I check view source code I can't find its html code but in Browser Inspect Element its code is visible.

Answer (score 1):

Jsoup can only parse the source code (right click > view source) as retrieved from the server.  However, your button is added to the dom (right click > inspect) using javascript.

To get the url, you need to render the page first and then pass the html to jsoup.

Here is an example of how to do it with [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/):

**page.html - source code**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="loadData.js"></script>
</head>
<body onLoad="loadData()">
    <div class="container">
        <table id="data" border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>col1</th>
                <th>col2</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**loadData.js**

```
    // append rows and cols to table.data in page.html
    function loadData() {
        data = document.getElementById("data");
        for (var row = 0; row < 2; row++) {
            var tr = document.createElement("tr");
            for (var col = 0; col < 2; col++) {
                td = document.createElement("td");
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(row + "." + col));
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
            data.appendChild(tr);
        }
    }
```

**page.html when loaded to browser**

| Col1 | Col2 |
| ------ | ------ |
| 0.0   | 0.1   |
| 1.0   | 1.1   |

**Using jsoup to parse page.html for col data**

```
    // load source from file
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new File("page.html"), "UTF-8");

    // iterate over row and col
    for (Element row : doc.select("table#data > tbody > tr"))

        for (Element col : row.select("td"))

            // print results
            System.out.println(col.ownText());
```

**Output**

(empty)

**What happened?**

Jsoup parses the source code as delivered from the server (or in this case loaded from file).  It does not invoke client-side actions such as JavaScript or CSS DOM manipulation.  In this example, the rows and cols are never appended to the data table.

**How to parse my page as rendered in the browser?**

```
    // load page using HTML Unit and fire scripts
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    HtmlPage myPage = webClient.getPage(new File("page.html").toURI().toURL());

    // convert page to generated HTML and convert to document
    doc = Jsoup.parse(myPage.asXml());

    // iterate row and col
    for (Element row : doc.select("table#data > tbody > tr"))

        for (Element col : row.select("td"))

            // print results
            System.out.println(col.ownText());

    // clean up resources        
    webClient.close();
```

**Output**

```
0.0
0.1
1.0
1.1
```

Comment: But HtmlUnit does not work on Android and selenium webdriver is not good because I have to create webview in activity.